# Executar JS inline dentro do retorno de um AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax

Tenho um hotsite que funciona em AJAX e urls amigáveis (mais especificamente com [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)). Onde o topo e rodapé são fixos, e somente o conteúdo são injetados na página.

O problema é que agora, não consigo executar o javascript inline das páginas de conteúdo.
Já li sobre dar `eval` no texto retornado, mas me parece que o `eval` é ruim para performance. Então como é a melhor forma de fazer (ou a que vocês costumam fazer)?

Comment: Creio que um exemplo mínimo de como você *faria* ajude o pessoal a entender o que você quer, exatamente.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que o PJAX deveria estar sim executando seus blocos `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`.

Você tem um exemplo de um bloco que não esteja sendo executado? Você colocou o atributo `type="text/javascript"` neles?